# Apple Music play count not syncing between iPhone and iTunes

Tags: iphone, ios, itunes, mac, apple-music

I'm running Apple Music on my mac and iPhone. I have an album in My Music, so the plays should be syncing, but the play count is not being effected by music played on my phone. Is there any trip to let the play count sync between devices? I know that the "love" are device specific, but I thought that play count should sync because it worked before Apple Music.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I can only get it to sync when I plug my iPhone to iTunes and sync it manually.

Comment: Please expand on your answer by providing some context and/or some links to references.  A single line answer is not very helpful to the community at large.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it takes a good while for the play counts to sync, but eventually they will. So wait a few hours and see if they've been updated.